# If I travel with 2 different companies will the second company that I check in with know my previous departure point?

Tags: air-travel

If I travel with 2 different companies will the second company that I check in with know my previous departure point?

How about if the tickets are booked separately but they are within the same company like Alliance airlines or something like this, would they be able to track the travel from the very first point of departure until the end of it?

Is there any way so that the second company that I will fly with, might not know where I'm flying from? And the same question would apply for the first company, so that they don't know whether I have another flight during a period of time.
Thanks

Comment: Why would they need to know?

Comment: Why would they know, simply. The data is not shared across airlines. I don't even think anyone will bother you if you buy two flights taking off at the same time from the same airport with the same airline with the same identity. Maybe your concerns are answered in this question: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13516/does-my-government-know-in-which-country-i-am-at-when-i-travel

Answer (score 3):

The second company that you're flying with would not know unless the itinerary is booked together, however there might be a passport stamp that you should worry about if you're travelling through an embargoed country.

However, countries like Cuba don't stamp your passport, they will give you a card with a stamp that you need to provide upon exit of the country. If you're traveling though a country that won't allow entry based on a previous itinerary (like going to Saudi Arabia after visiting Israel), make sure the previous country gives you a visa card and doesn't stamp your passport. Happy travels!